# What is the best way to write a simple condition in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, ecmascript-6, jsx

in my jsx

```
<div>{person.age}</div>
```

I want to display below only if the person is age 50 or above

```
<div className="red-text">{person.age}</div>
```

to do this I put a var     `let olderPerson = person.age > 50;` and then did this

```
{
    olderPerson ? (
        <div className="red-text">{person.age }</div>
    ) : (<div >{person.age }</div>)
}
```

LMK if this correct way to do this

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html read up on conditional rendering in the docs, I tend to avoid ternary if I can, it makes code harder to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yea correct.

```
        {
        olderPerson ?
            <div className="red-text">{person.age }</div> :
            <div >{person.age }</div>
        }
```

in this case you could also make the classname conditional.

```
        {
        <div className={olderPerson && "red-text"}>
            {person.age }
        </div>
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

https://jsfiddle.net/enf2q4eg/

Age passed via props in `Example` component.